# Обновить высоту iframe с динамическим содержимым

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Народ помогите реализовать. Есть iframe который загружается по всему содержимому страницы. Однако если на странице iframe выполнены какие-то действия затрагивавшее высоту - все рушится. Есть ли способ автоматического обновления высоты содержимого например через 1 секунду или автоматической высоты.

```js
function sizeFrame(frame) {
  if(frame.contentDocument) {
    frame.height = frame.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  } else {
    frame.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
  }
}
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" id="myframe" src="../index.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" onload="sizeFrame(this)"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var lastHeight = 0, curHeight = 0, $frame = $('iframe:eq(0)');
  setInterval(function(){
    curHeight = $frame.contents().find('body').height();
    if ( curHeight != lastHeight ) {
      $frame.css('height', (lastHeight = curHeight) + 'px' );
    }
  },500);
});
```

Спс - ваши минусы заставляют гуглить и  использовать 100 вариантов - прежде чем решениебудет найдено.